# Match item before specified item

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have following list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="parent">1.</li>
  <li class="child">1. first</li>
  <li class="child">1. second</li>
  <li class="child">1. third</li>

  <li class="parent">2.</li>
  <li class="child">2. first</li>
  <li class="child">2. second</li>
  <li class="child">2. third</li>
  <li class="child">2. fourth</li>
  <li class="child">2. fifth</li>

  <li class="parent">3.</li>
  <li class="child">3. first</li>
  <li class="child">3. second</li>
  <li class="child">3. third</li>
  <li class="child">3. fourth</li>

  <li class="parent">4.</li>
  <li class="child">4. first</li>
  <li class="child">4. second</li>
  <li class="child">4. third</li>
</ul>
```

I want to set specified background for `first` and last elements. While I have no problem with the `first`:

```
.parent + .child {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

then I do not know what to do with the lasts.

Simply: I want to match `.child` before `.parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jquery `.prev()` selector:

`$('.parent').prev().css( "background-color", "red" );`

http://jsfiddle.net/gC53q/1/

There is no previous-child selector in CSS. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector)

Answer (score 2):

```
li:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

You are looking for the nth-child selector. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mKH7j/

Comment: Sorry, I had to modify my question. I need to match `1. third`, `2. fifth`, `3. fourth`, `4. third`

Comment: I would use `$('.parent').prev().css('background-color','red');
$('ul li').last().css('background-color','red');`

http://jsfiddle.net/mKH7j/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want the third of the three child selectors, so select the third sibling:

`.child + .child + .child {
    background-color: red;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/gC53q/

Comment: Sorry, I had to modify my question. I need to match `1. third`, `2. fifth`, `3. fourth`, `4. third`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one without jquery:

```
li:nth-child(2n) { background: red; }
li:nth-child(4n) { background: whitesmoke; }
```

And here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G8vCZ/1/